# Getting ID from a PHP script and inplement in a URL

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass in the URL an ID from the following PHP script:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($EditProductInformations as $EditProductInformation) :
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <select class="produkteSelect" name="produkt[]">
                            <?php foreach ($resultsProdukt as $resultp) { ?>
                                <option value="<?= $resultp["ProduktID"] ?>" <?php if($resultp["ProduktID"] == $EditProductInformation["ProduktID"]): ?>selected<?php endif; ?>><?= $resultp["produktname"] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10"> <input type="text" class="formcontrol" placeholder="https://" name="url" value="<?= $EditProductInformation['url']; ?>"></div>
                <p> <div class="col-2">  <a onclick="confirmDeleting(id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger product-delete" href="#" id="<?= $EditProductInformation['ID'] ?>"><i id="produktDel" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>  </a> </div> </p> 
            </div>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

this so my js script so far:

```
    function confirmDeleting(elemen) {
        let confirmDeleting = confirm("are you sure, you want to delete?");
        if (confirmDeleting) {
            console.log(elemen);
            window.location.href="formprocess.php?dfID=" + elemen.dataset.id;
            }
        }
```

My URL is good so far, but I cant reach the `ID`

```
"formprocess.php?dfID=undefined"
```

is the URL but I want that it will be

```
"formprocess.php?dfID=144"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to use the function confirmDeleting without ```this``` while calling, then in the function syntax just use event.currentTarget.dataset.id

Comment: Your `a` element does not appear to have a dataset attribute

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I added now in my `a` an attribute like 

`<a onclick="confirmDeleting()" class="btn btn-outline-danger product-delete" href="#" id="<?= $EditProductInformation['ID'] ?>">` . Is this right?

Comment: Just put the id as an argument of the function confirmDeleting instead of this

Comment: @R4ncid i did it already and it remains "undefind"

Comment: I can see no dataset attribute - can you update the question?

Comment: In case you're not familiar with dataset, here's a link: [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing 'this' as a parameter to the confirmDeleting() function, you can give it as a parameter directly the ID of the product concerned.
So the code will be:

```
<a onclick="confirmDeleting(<?php echo $resultp["ProductID"] ?>)" class="btn btn-outline-danger product-delete" ><i id="productDel" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></a>
```

Then you will only have to retrieve the ID parameter in your JS function

```
function confirmDeleting(ProductID) {
let confirmDeleting = confirm("are you sure, you want to delete?");
if (confirmDeleting) {
    console.log(ProductID);
    window.location.href="formprocess.php?dfID=" + ProductID;
    }
}
```

Comment: A good answer includes a proper explanation for what was wrong, what you've change and why. Just posting code without any explanation isn't that constructive. Future visitors might have the same issue but with code that looks slightly different so explaining the answer is important. Give a man a fish vs teaching them to fish and all that...

Comment: @KomlanMawulomHounkpatiAnani sadly it dont work in my script.

It says in the log $resultp is undefined

Comment: @Lampi Because `$resultp` is a PHP variable and should be echo'd/output via PHP

Comment: @M.Eriksson Sorry I didn't know that...I'll do that next time.

Comment: @Lampi yes the echo is missing... the code should be: <a onclick="confirmDeleting(<?=$resultp["ProductID"]?>)"

Comment: @Lampi but the method of setting a data-id attribute in the DOM and getting it in JS with element.getgetAttribute() also works

Comment: _"I'll do that next time"_ - Why next time?  Just [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72977046/edit) and include some explanation.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Okay

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any dataset attribute, and all attribute value of element will be in string, so better if you have custom attribute of your element
Something like this:

```
<a onclick="confirmDeleting(this)" data-id="<?php echo $resultp[\"ProduktID\"]; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-danger product-delete" href="#">
```

And you can access that attribute by:

```
elemen.getAttribute("data-id");
```

Also if you are using `JQuery` you can do it like this:

```
$(elemen).data("id");
```

Comment: That would make `data-id` the `string` "$resultp[\"ProduktID\"]" - you'd need to echo/output that variable via PHP

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to add it and the `<?php ?>`

Comment: @Lampi sure no problem